# How to get Rows only in df1, Rows only in df2 , Columns with unequal values using Pandas dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have two pandas dataframe (df1, and df2). In here, I am providing a sample, in the real scenario, there are hundreds of columns with **different data types** and **millions of rows**.The data types don't always match in both dataframes. How can I get the rows that exist only in df1 and the rows that only exist in df2. Also, for which columns, the row changed?

**Expected Output:**

**1) Rows only in df1
2) Rows only in df2
3) Columns with unequal values**

```
"df1":
id   Name   score (datatype = integer)  isEnrolled (dt = sting)     Comment (dt =string)       Rank (dt = integer)
111  Jack   2.17                        True                        He was late to class       2.3
112  Nick   1.11                        False                       Graduated                  3.3
113  Zoe    4.12                        True                                                   4.5
114  Dan    4.12                        True                                                   4.5

"df2":
id   Name   score (datatype = object)   isEnrolled (dt = string)    Comment (dt = string)           Reason                Date            Rank(dt = float)
111  Jack   2.17                        True                        He was late to class            He was sleeping       03/23/2018      5.6
112  Nick   1.11                        False                       He was late to class                                  04/22/2017      3.3
113  Zoe    4.14                        False                       On vacation                     He is travelling
```

[image: Two pandas dataframes]